# play video without enabling javascript

Tags: javascript, embed, vimeo

Is there a way we can play an embedded video in browser without JavaScript enabled, may be using a library or some thing.
I have a project where i need to show the video on homepage through vimeo, however the client wants that it should be played even if the user has JavaScript enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [HTML5 Video](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
     <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
     Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo's embed code is `<iframe>`-based and still works when JavaScript is disabled. Click the paper plane "Share" symbol on the relevant Vimeo video to get the video's embed code.